# pdfmake + AngularJS + Electron creates _blank pdf

Tags: angularjs, electron, pdfmake

I've a problem using the library [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) in a AngularJS and Electron. The pdf saves in blank.

The code is:

```
.service('PDFService', function() {

   this.createPdfOne = function(data) {

    const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
    const choice = dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: [ 'createDirectory', 'openDirectory']});
    var docDefinition = {
        content: [
            'First paragraph',
            'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
        ]
    };

    var fs = require('fs');
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBuffer(function(result) {
        fs.writeFileSync(choice + '/sample.pdf', result);
    });
  };

});
```

**UPDATE: FIXED PROBLEM**

I use:

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download()
```

Instead of:

```
 var fs = require('fs');
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBuffer(function(result) {
        fs.writeFileSync(choice + '/sample.pdf', result);
 });
```

Comment: from what i can tell, you can use `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('FILENAME.pdf');` https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/116

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Thanks, this works perfectly

Comment: since you confirmed it worked, i posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

The repo [documentation](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) does not mention this but there was an issue found [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/116) asking the same question. It was closed saying that you could do something like:

`pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('FILENAME.pdf');`